# Program in Prolog that returns change

Tags: prolog

I want to write a program that returns change in Prolog, I tried this predicate but I'm not sure about it, cuz I wanted to do the same as in the C/C++ program. If Anyone has a correction about that I would appreciate it.

```
dollar(100).
quarter(25).
dime(1).


return(0,0,0).
return(Amount_recieved,Amount_due,Change) :-
   Change is Amount_recieved - Amount_due.

dollar(100) is Change / 100 , Change is Change mod 100.
quarter(25) is Change /25 , Change is Change mod 25.
dime(1) is Change
```

Comment: Let me guess: you want a predicate that, given an amount received and given an amount due, return (unify, expressing it in Prolog terms) `Change` expressed with a triple (dollars, quarters and dimes) maximizing first the dollars and second the quarters? If so: `Amount_received` and `Amount_due` are expressed in dimes or in triples (dollars, quarters and dimes)?

Comment: Yeah right I want them expressed in triples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following solution based on a struct `amount/3` with the number of dollars (first value), of quarters (second value) and dimes (third value)

```
getAmountInDimes(amount(Do, Qu, Di), AmountInDimes) :-
  AmountInDimes is (Do * 100) + (Qu * 25) + Di.

getAmountTriple(AmountInDimes, amount(Do, Qu, Di)) :-
  Do  is AmountInDimes div 100,
  Mid is AmountInDimes mod 100,
  Qu  is Mid div 25,
  Di  is Mid mod 25.

computeChange(AReceived, ADue, Change) :- 
  getAmountInDimes(AReceived, ARDimes),
  getAmountInDimes(ADue, ADDimes),
  ARDimes >= ADDimes,
  CDimes is ARDimes - ADDimes,
  getAmountTriple(CDimes, Change).
```

The following is an example of use

```
computeChange(amount(20, 0, 0), amount(15, 2, 12), Ch)
```

that unify `Ch` with `amount(4,1,13)`.

Another example

```
computeChange(amount(20, 0, 0), amount(15, 2, 12), amount(Do, Qu, Di))
```

that directly unify `Do` with 4, `Qu` with 1 and `Di` with 13.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same solution but only with dollars and I must tell the details of the change, for example:
computeChange(amount(20),amount(8),ch)
1 bill of 10$
1 bill of 1$

Comment: @Ilyes.B - 20 minus 8 is 12 so, I suppose, one bill of 10$ and *two* bills of 1$. Anyway, yes, I suppose it's possible and I suppose you can understand how examining my example. First of all you have to fix the value of the money (coins and bills) you want to use.

Comment: ' bill(2000).
bill(1000).
bill(500).
coin(200).
coin(100).
coin(50).
coin(20).
coin(10).
coin(5).
coin(2).
coin(1).

getAmountInDimes(amount(bill(X),coin(Y)),Amount) :- Amount is (bill(X) * 2000) + (coin(Y)* 200).

getAmountTriple(Amount, amount(bill(X), coin(Y))) :-
 bill(X) is Amount div 2000,
 Mid is Amount mod 2000,
 coin(Y) is Mid div 200.


computeChange(AReceived, ADue, Change) :-
 getAmountInDimes(AReceived, ARDimes),
 getAmountInDimes(ADue, ADDimes),
 ARDimes >= ADDimes,
 CDimes is ARDimes - ADDimes,
 getAmountTriple(CDimes, Change). '

Correct it please!

Comment: @Ilyes.B - I don't know how "correct"; your modifications are totally incompatible with the code I've proposed. And with 11 values available a solution based on a struct with a field for every value is (IMHO) senseless. In this case i think is better a solution based on a list of couples (value and number of bills/coins); a totally different solution.